# Wordpress site is not displaying correctly in internet explorer after server transfer

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser, web-testing, server.transfer

I have an odd issue.

A site that I'm building stopped displaying correctly in IE 8/9 after transferring it to another server. I can't figure out what is wrong with the site. I am starting to suspect that it is server related.

Has anyone a clue why?

Old server (working in IE)
goo.gl/9XZpD

New server (not working in IE) 
goo.gl/S5kZf

Comment: What do you mean by "not displaying correctly"?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 404 errors on two fonts files - eurosti-webfont.woff and ufonts.com_eurostile-bold-2-webfont.woff.  Looks like they didn't make the transition to the new server.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have corrected the missing fonts. Seems that font-face got lost on the way. Still this didn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your page still starts with:

```
<?


?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

remove the php short tags, the file has to start like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Edit:
if you have access to your php.ini file look for

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

change it to

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Restart apache

Cheers

Dario

Comment: Also make sure you have these lines at the beginning:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Exensor</TITLE>`

Than empty your IE cache. 
The reason is that your document is displayed in non standard mode

Comment: Thanks for responding. Still not working even after removing the PHP tags.

Comment: I'm still seeing the php tags on the live site.